# vectorWeights not filled for text2vec-transformers

Tags: object, graphql, weaviate

Not sure if this is a bug or the intended behaviour but while using text2vec-transformers as a default vectorizer, graphQl nearText is working ok. So it retrieved nearby objects. However, the field vectorWeights of object are empty.

Is that expected and why cant we directly have the vector available in that field.

Do you have to manually call the endpoint for each of your object a second time and store those values in a custom property?

Comment: Can you share your query, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vector` of an object is stored under the `_additional` property. You can edit your `nearText` query to return this field this property like in this [example](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/additional-properties#vector)